# Laravel - Ajax Powered Pages and also have forms that Post causing issues

Tags: php, ajax, forms, laravel, laravel-5

Im building a site where the pages load via ajax, I have a contact form that posts via ajax so I think its triggering by my post route.. Im just looking for the best way to distinguish between page navigations posts and form posts on the pages so that they dont conflict. My routes look like this for the contact page

```
Route::any('/contact',   function(){
    return view('frontend.contact');
});

Route::post('/contact', array( 'as' => 'contactform.create',  'uses' => 'ContactFormController@validateandsave'));
```

and the form is laid out as follows

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/contact',  'route' => 'contactform.create', 'files' => false,  'method' => 'post', 'id'=>'updateform' ,'role'=>"form" )) !!}   

<span class="input input--kozakura">
{!! Form::text('full_name', '', array('class' => 'full_name input__field input__field--kozakura')) !!}
</span>

<span class="input input--kozakura">
{!! Form::email('email', 'paddy@gmail.com', array('class' => 'email input__field input__field--kozakura')) !!}
</span>

<span class="input input--kozakura">
{!! Form::text('current_website', 'www.lassiemarlowe.com', array('class' => 'current_website input__field input__field--kozakura')) !!}
</span>

<div class="submit-btn-wrapper">
{!! Form::submit('submit') !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

so how do I distinguish between a page ajax post and the form ajax post ?

Answer (score 0):

Place the post definition before other one:

```
Route::post('/contact', array( 'as' => 'contactform.create',  'uses' => 'ContactFormController@validateandsave'));

Route::any('/contact',   function(){

                return view('frontend.contact');

            });
```

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately - Im supprised theres not more documentation on this kind of setup

Comment: @HamburgersnHeroin Can you describe the issue a little more.

Comment: Basically the pages are loaded via ajax, when a link is clicked its rel value is used by jquery to call the url via post, then the contents of the page are pulled in and inserted into the section.. this all works fine. the issue is when you go to the contact page as it has a form that carries out its own ajax post requests

Comment: @HamburgersnHeroin Is it possible for you to use a different route for that form? eg: `Route::post('/contact/update', ... );`

Comment: Ive actually tried that but it doesnt work, its tricky to explain but it basically has to be all controlled by the contact page.. Ive read stuff about laravel jobs but surely theres a simple way.. is it possible to associate a route with a specific html link so that when you click on contacts link it fires one route

Comment: @HamburgersnHeroin Sorry, Im having a hard time understanding your issue. Try being as elaborate as possible in the original post

Comment: Basically I need a way to distinguish between a form posting and a page load that uses Ajax post

Answer (score 0):

Use route group is the good way to differentiate your routing. My solution would be like this.

```
// all normal routes in website here
Route::any('contact', function(){
    return view('frontend.contact'); // this will produce example.com/contact
});

// all ajax call
Route::group(['prefix' => 'ajax'], function () {
    Route::post('contact', 'ContactFormController@validateandsave') // this will produce example.com/ajax/contact
});
```

also use action('ControllerName@methodName') to generate url for the form 'action' attribute. This will changed dynamically based on your router.php file

see detail here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-action

Answer (score 0):

From your latest comment on @AngadDubey's answer it looks like the problem isn't that the two routes (post and any) are conflicting, but that you actually need two different handlers to handle an AJAX XHR POST versus a normal browser form HTTP POST.

At a guess this is because, although the forms will be handled similarly, the way of passing back errors or success messages will be different depending on what's going on.

I would say don't actually separate them out, but instead put some detection in that action when you need to hand something back. So process the POST input as normal (as the normal form and the AJAX form should be the same, right?) but then when it comes to returning a response, use something like `app('request')->ajax()` to determine if the request came through an XHR.

Alternatively, you can use the same detection to split the processing up if they really can't be processed using the same validation and processing code.